Why is the Blue camera angle advantageous?
It's generally accepted that the Blue (bottom-left) team in League of Legends has an advantage over the Red (top-right) side due to the camera angle. This is not just anecdotal, as there's an actual difference in win rate.
What specifically about the Blue side's camera angle accounts for this advantage?

I searched for an existing question about this and was shocked not to find one - If I missed one my apologies

This article on UnrankedSmurfs brings up a few interesting points:

The blue jungler has an easier time accessing the dragon pit which is important during the early game.
Due to the pits the distance between the pit and the blue-side top lane (assuming you do not go in directly through the river) is rather long for the red-side jungler. Ganking the top lane when it is pushed in may be harder.
The red buff is located between the top and mid lane for the red-side jungler. Since the mid lane minions arrive rather early to the party this player is unlikely to help kill the buff. For the blue-side jungler there's more consistent help in form of the ADC and support player.

Regarding the camera angle:

Since the camera angle is not flat from the top but slightly tilted you can see more on the top of the screen than the bottom (where the HUD is). Since blue-side players work their way to the top of the screen they may have an easier time targeting enemies or keeping track of them.

